# How to Store data of selected day - Start Time and End Time in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to store selected day Start time and end time in particular Object. Can some tell me how to do that in angular

[UI Used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r09JV.jpg)

Comment: First try to add your solution write some code give it try google it and then ask question.

Comment: Use the date pipe 
e.g.   {{ timestamp | date : 'EEEE' }}